# Loop through nested Retrofit JSON results

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have a JSON response that looks like this:

```
{
  "1":{
    "id":"1",
    "user_id":"1",
    "children":[
    {
      "id":"2",
      "user_id":"2",
      "children":[
      {
        "id":"3",
        "user_id":"3",
        "children":[
        {
          "id":"4",
          "user_id":"2",
          "children":[]
        }]
      },
      {
        "id":"5",
        "user_id":"1",
        "children":[
      ]
      }
    ]
    },
    {
      "id":"6",
      "user_id":"2",
      "children":[
      ]
    }
  ]
  },
  "7":{
    "id":"7",
    "user_id":"2",
    ...
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have nested arrays (`children`). I need to loop through this JSON response, going through each nested array until it runs into an empty `children` array, and then takes a step back to continue to the rest of the items.

I made a model class for the response, so my current code looks like this:

```
RestClient.getService().getParents(new Callback<ParentResponse>() {
  @Override
  public void success(ParentResponse parentData, Response response) {
    for (Parent parent : parentData.getData()) {
      //
    }
  }
}
```

Which obviously only iterates through the top-level items (id `1` and `7` in my case).

The model for the `Parent` class looks like this:

```
public class Parent {
  private String id;
  private String userId;
  private List<Parent> parents = new ArrayList<Parent>();

  // get/set for id and userId

  public List<Parent> getParents() {
    return parents;
  }

  public void setParents(List<Parent> parents) {
    this.parents = parents;
  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try recursion...

```
protected void doSomething(Parent p) { 
     ... some code here for all parents
     if (p.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
          ... some code here for empty parents
     } else { 
          for(Parent child : getChildren()) { 
              doSomething( child ); 
          }
     }
}
```

Another simple idea...

```
public void doSomething(Parent p) {
  Queue<Parent> toGo = new LinkedList<Parent>(p.getChildren());
  while(!toGo.isEmpty()) {
     Parent toDo = toGo.poll();
     // do something with the element, if you need to
     toGo.addAll( toGo.getChildren() );
  }
}
```

Of course, with this you will not get the ordering you want, so you might want to play around with that solution a bit. But it might give you an idea how to start...

Comment: What would go within my foreach loop?

Comment: Well, obviously `doSomething(parent);`